# Массовое изменение кодировки файлов

Tags: windows, кодировка

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть файлы, они все в кодировке cp1251, мне нужно пересохранить их в кодировке utf-8. Вручную через редактор не вариант, так как файлов более 1000 шт. 
Подскажите пожалуйста какой-нибудь оптимальный способ.

Comment: Вы б хотя бы ОС указали. А когда укажете - попробуйте сами поискать под неё перекодировщик. Наверняка найдётся не один, и даже не один десяток.

Comment: windows 7. я нашел пару программ, но они мне не помогли

Comment: Без указания, на каком языке должно быть решение, выходит, что вопрос является запросом рекомендации, какой тулзой воспользоваться, а это вне формата данного сайта.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Не работаю с Windows, но могу предложить решение для любой системы, если у вас установлен интерпретатор Python 3:

```python
import os
from glob import glob

for filename in glob('*.txt'):   # задаёте шаблон для файлов
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='cp1251') as in_file:
        raw_filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        # добавляем суффикс имени файла, можно добавить папку
        new_filename = raw_filename + '-unicode' + ext
        with open(new_filename, 'w') as out_file:
            # записываем информацию
            out_file.write(in_file.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

Для файлов в текущем каталоге:

```
for /r %%a in (*.php) do "перекодировщик %%a"
```

где "перекодировщик" - выбранный вами перекодировщик с нужными ключами командной строки, в `%%a` будет содержаться имя файла.

Answer (score 2):

так как автор не указал ни в тексте вопроса, ни с помощью меток, свою операционную систему, а ответ на вопрос может быть интересен и пользователям операционной системы `gnu/linux`, приведу ответ и для неё:

```
$ for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" tmpfile; cat tmpfile | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 > "$f"; done; rm tmpfile
```

для всех файлов, имеющих суффикс `.txt` в текущем каталоге, будет произведено перекодирование их содержимого из кодировки *cp1251* в кодировку *utf8*.

Comment: В принципе, ОС была указана в комментарии

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, я знаю.

Comment: Добавлю: `cygwin` позволит запустить эту команду и на windows.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой [uconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) из библиотеки [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), которая является аналогом iconv и портирована на Виндоуз.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Childitem d:\*.txt -File | foreach {$a=Get-Item $_ ; $b="d:\utf\"+$a.Name ; Get-Content $a | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath $b}
```

Powershell, для файлов внутри одной директории. Есть в windows 7 по умолчанию.
Можно добавить -recurse для всех вложенных папок.
Можно читать пути из файла :
Get-Content d:\files.txt